# Python / BeautifulSoup - Code showing IndexError

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

My code gives an IndexError. I am not able to figure out why. Please help.

This is my code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Dregan.html'

for i in range(7):
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    tags = soup('a')
    lst = list()

    for tag in tags:
        a = tag.get('href',None)
        lst.append(a)
    url = lst[17]

print url
```

I get the following IndexError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    url = lst[17]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many items are in `lst`?

Comment: more than 18, plus the same error would show even if I change it to lst[2]

Comment: How many exactly though? Print how many there are.

Comment: can you print the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, the code works OK for me. Maybe it is a network related problem in which the content of the page didn't load as it was supposed.
Does the problem occur every time you run the code?

Comment: That's super weird! I copied and pasted the code I posted here and it runs well. But when I run the code where I wrote in my text editor before having transferred it here, it shows me the error..

Comment: I just tried indenting line 15 (`url = lst[17]`) and it throws the error you mentioned before.  Maybe that's the problem you are facing in your code.